# How to use pytest-custom_exit_code plugin

Tags: python, pytest

Need help!
I have a job on Gitlab ci, that runs tests and reruns failed ones. If there are no failed tests, job fails with exit code 5, that means that there are no tests for running. I found out that there is plugin  "pytest-custom_exit_code", but I don't know how to correctly use it.
I need just to add command 'pytest --suppress-no-test-exit-code' to my runner.sh?
It looks like this now:

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/local/bin/pytest -m test 
/usr/local/bin/pytest -m --last-failed --last-failed-no-failures none test
```

Comment: Well, what happens when you add `--suppress-no-test-exit-code` to your `runner.sh`?

Comment: @larsks this happend: ERROR: usage: pytest [options] [file_or_dir] [file_or_dir] [...]
pytest: error: unrecognized arguments: --suppress-no-test-exit-code
  inifile: None
  rootdir: /builds/advertising/autotests
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:01
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 4

Answer (score 0):

Assumption here is that plugin is installed first using

```
pip install pytest-custom_exit_code
```

command like option `pytest --suppress-no-test-exit-code` should work after that.

If configuration file like .pytest.ini is used , following lines should be added in it

```
[pytest]
addopts = --suppress-no-test-exit-code
```